# Making my character fight

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm trying to create a beat em up game and right now i got my character walking and jumping. I have 3 attack animation so far and works just about. This is what i'm trying to achieve, if the player presses the attack button then the character will attack and if the player keeps pressing the attack button it will continue with its attack/punching sequence or if a different attack key is pressed it will switch attack/kicking animation (Note: I do no want if the player holds down the key, has to be a key press).

Also how can i make it go to the next attack animation once the current attack animation has completely finished instead of jumping to the next frame midway of it's current attack animation. So while the character is attacking and the attack key is pressed the character will finish its current attack animation and as soon as it ends it moves on to the next attack animation frame otherwise it will stop. I'm not sure how i can do this, should i create arrays or extend classes. I want to create the game like this a copy i found but its in AS2

https://www.dropbox.com/s/zhf68zmi0ktmeqq/DD%20%282%29.zip

This is what i have done so far

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
    import flash.ui.Keyboard;
    import flash.utils.*;
    import com.greensock.TweenLite;
    import com.greensock.easing.*;
    import com.greensock.plugins.*;

    public class Player extends MovieClip
    {
        TweenPlugin.activate([BlurFilterPlugin]);
        //Player run speed setting;
        var RunSpeed:Number = 8;
        //Player key presses
        var RightKeyPress:Boolean = false;
        var LeftKeyPress:Boolean = false;
        var UpKeyPress:Boolean = false;
        //Jump variables
        var Gravity:Number = 1.5;
        var JumpPower:Number = 0;
        var CanJump:Boolean = false;
        var Jumped:Boolean = false;
        //Dash variable
        var Pressed:Boolean = false;
        var LastKeyPressed:Number = -1;
        var DashAmount:Number = 250;
        var DoubleTapDelay:Number = 260;//-- delay in milliseconds
        var Dashing:Boolean = false;
        var RightDash:Boolean = false;
        var LeftDash:Boolean = false;

        public function Player()
        {
            stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN,KeyDown);
            stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN,KeyPressed);
            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,Update);
        }

        function KeyDown(event:KeyboardEvent)
        {
            stage.removeEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, SecondDash);
            //If key is down cannot dash
            RightDash = false;
            LeftDash = false;

            //When Key is Down
            if (event.keyCode == 39)
            {
                RightKeyPress = true;
            }

            if (event.keyCode == 37)
            {
                LeftKeyPress = true;
            }

            if (event.keyCode == 38)
            {
                UpKeyPress = true;
            }
        }

        function KeyPressed(event:KeyboardEvent):void
        {
            stage.removeEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, KeyPressed);
            stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, KeyUp);

            //If on floor
            if (CanJump)
            {
                //If right key is down
                if (event.keyCode == 39)
                {
                    if (event.keyCode == 39 && Pressed)
                    {
                        //If right key press matches with recent right key press, dash right
                        Dashing = true;
                        RightDash = true;
                    }
                    Pressed = true;
                    setTimeout(function(){Pressed = false}, DoubleTapDelay);
                }

                if (event.keyCode == 37)
                {
                    if (event.keyCode == 37 && Pressed)
                    {
                        //If left key press matches with recent left key press, dash left
                        Dashing = true;
                        LeftDash = true;
                    }
                    Pressed = true;
                    setTimeout(function(){Pressed = false}, DoubleTapDelay);
                }

            }
        }



        function Update(event:Event)
        {

            //Adding gravity to the game world
            JumpPower +=  Gravity;
            //if player is more than 300 on the y-axis
            if (this.y > 300)
            {
                //Player stays on the ground and can jump
                JumpPower = 0;
                CanJump = true;
            }


                //If already jumped and on floor
                if (Jumped == true && CanJump)
                {
                    //Cannot jump again
                    CanJump = false;

                    //If on floor and right key is pressed run right
                    if ((RightKeyPress))
                    {
                        gotoAndStop('Run');
                        scaleX = 1;
                    }
                    else if ((LeftKeyPress))
                    {
                        //Otherwise if on floor and left key is pressed run left
                        gotoAndStop('Run');
                        scaleX = -1;
                    }

                    //If no key is pressed stay idle
                    if ((!RightKeyPress && !LeftKeyPress))
                    {
                        gotoAndStop('Idle');
                    }
                }


                //If on floor and can jump
                if (CanJump)
                {
                    //If right key is pressed run right
                    if ((RightKeyPress))
                    {
                        x +=  RunSpeed;
                        gotoAndStop('Run');
                        scaleX = 1;
                    }
                    else if ((LeftKeyPress))
                    {
                        //otherwise if left key is pressed run left
                        x -=  RunSpeed;
                        gotoAndStop('Run');
                        scaleX = -1;
                    }

                    if ((UpKeyPress))
                    {
                        //If up key is pressed then jump
                        JumpPower = -15;
                        CanJump = false;
                        gotoAndStop('Jump');
                        Jumped = true;
                    }

                    //If no key is pressed stay idle
                    if ((!RightKeyPress && !LeftKeyPress && CanJump))
                    {
                        gotoAndStop('Idle');
                    }
                }
                else if (CanJump == false)
                {
                    //Otherwise if in air and right key is pressed move right
                    if ((RightKeyPress))
                    {
                        x +=  RunSpeed;
                        scaleX = 1;
                    }
                    else if ((LeftKeyPress))
                    {
                        //Otherwise if left key is pressed then move left
                        x -=  RunSpeed;
                        scaleX = -1;
                    }
                }


                //If Dashing is true
                if (Dashing == true)
                {
                    //Dash right
                    if (RightDash == true)
                    {
                        stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, SecondDash);
                        stage.removeEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, KeyPressed);
                        TweenLite.to(this,0,{blurFilter:{blurX:1000}});
                        TweenLite.to(this,0.2,{blurFilter:{blurX:0},x:x + DashAmount,ease:Expo.easeOut});
                        Dashing = false;
                    }
                    else if (LeftDash == true)
                    {
                        //Otherwise dash left
                        stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, SecondDash);
                        stage.removeEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, KeyPressed);
                        TweenLite.to(this,0,{blurFilter:{blurX:1000}});
                        TweenLite.to(this,0.2,{blurFilter:{blurX:0},x:x - DashAmount,ease:Expo.easeOut});
                        Dashing = false;
                    }
                }
                else if (Dashing == false)
                {
                    stage.removeEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, SecondDash);
                }


            this.y +=  JumpPower;
        }


        function SecondDash(event:KeyboardEvent)
        {
            stage.removeEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, SecondDash);

            if (event.keyCode == 38)
            {
                TweenLite.to(this,0,{blurFilter:{blurX:0}});
                TweenLite.to(this,0,{blurFilter:{blurY:1000}});
                TweenLite.to(this,0.5,{blurFilter:{blurY:0},y:y - DashAmount,ease:Expo.easeOut});
            }
        }

        function KeyUp(event:KeyboardEvent)
        {
            stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, KeyPressed);
            RightDash = false;
            LeftDash = false;

            if (event.keyCode == 39)
            {
                RightKeyPress = false;
            }

            if (event.keyCode == 37)
            {
                LeftKeyPress = false;
            }

            if (event.keyCode == 38)
            {
                UpKeyPress = false;
                Jumped = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you have not even attempted to try and do the attack animations...at least from what I see in your code. It would be helpful to learn if you at least tried on your own, and then posted, but with that said, I'll give you some starting points. Also, I'm not sure if you're using a document class and other classes to make this game, or if you are just using the timeline.....the following will be for using classes. If you aren't using classes...stop now, and go learn what AS3 really is. You never want to code on the timeline in AS3 if possible.

Let's say we have 3 attacks, consisting of the keys "1", "2", and "3". Put these variables up top with your other variables...right after your `var LeftDash:Boolean = False` is fine. (Also, just change all of your `var` to `private var`....if that doesn't work just use `public var`....just for completeness)

```
private var attack1Boolean:Boolean = false;
private var attack2Boolean:Boolean = false;
private var attack3Boolean:Boolean = false;
```

Next do pretty much the same thing you do with the keydown and keyup for the arrow keys. Put the following somewhere inside your `KeyDown` method.

```
if (event.keyCode == 49)
{
    attack1Boolean = true;
}
if (event.keyCode == 50)
{
    attack2Boolean = true;
}
if (event.keyCode == 51)
{
    attack3Boolean = true;
}
```

and then in your `KeyUp` method, add the following

```
if (event.keyCode == 49)
{
    attack1Boolean = false;
}
if (event.keyCode == 50)
{
    attack2Boolean = false;
}
if (event.keyCode == 51)
{
    attack3Boolean = false;
}
```

Now you are ready to start implementing the attacks. You say you have created 3 animations for the attacks already. This means each attack should have it's own timeline (you could have all 3 on one timeline, but separated by frames as well, but I wouldn't recommend this). In order to do what you want (finish each animation before the next attack ensues) you will have to utilize `gotoAndStop` or `gotoAndPlay`.

It is most useful to create a new .as file for each of your animations. If you have all 3 animations combined into one timeline...that's fine just create 1 new .as file instead of 3. Now link them all normally like you would (if you don't know how to do this...once again...go do a real AS3 tutorial...you're getting ahead of yourself).

You will have to create an instance of these new class files, so at the top under your vars, put the following (if you name your new classes `Animation1`, `Animation2`...etc.)

```
private var animation1:Animation1;
private var animation2:Animation2;
private var animation3:Animation3;
```

Then in function `Player` put

```
animation1 = new Animation1();
animation2 = new Animation2();
animation3 = new Animation3();
```

Now your animations should be ready to use. Go to your `Update` method and add the following

```
//note, the animation1.currentFrame == 1 doesn't have to be 1...it's just the initial starting frame of the animation
if (attack1Boolean && 
    animation1.currentFrame == 1 &&
    animation2.currentFrame == 1 && 
    animation3.currentFrame == 1)
{
    animation1.x = //character.x if you have a class...this.x for yours
    animation1.y = //character.y if you have a class...this.y for yours
    addChild(animation1);
    attack1Boolean = false;
    if (animation1.currentFrame = //the last frame of animation1...a number)
    {
        animation1.gotoAndStop(1);
        removeChild(animation1);
    }
}

if (attack2Boolean && 
    animation1.currentFrame == 1 &&
    animation2.currentFrame == 1 && 
    animation3.currentFrame == 1)
{
    animation2.x = //character.x if you have a class...this.x for yours
    animation2.y = //character.y if you have a class...this.y for yours
    addChild(animation2);
    attack2Boolean = false;
    if (animation2.currentFrame = //the last frame of animation2...a number)
    {
        animation2.gotoAndStop(1);
        removeChild(animation2);
    }
}

if (attack3Boolean && 
    animation1.currentFrame == 1 &&
    animation2.currentFrame == 1 && 
    animation3.currentFrame == 1)
{
    animation3.x = //character.x if you have a class...this.x for yours
    animation3.y = //character.y if you have a class...this.y for yours
    addChild(animation3);
    attack3Boolean = false;
    animation3.gotoAndStop(1);
    if (animation3.currentFrame = //the last frame of animation3...a number)
    {
        animation3.gotoAndStop(1);
        removeChild(animation3);
    }
}
```

That should start the character animation and make it so we can only use one attack once the others are finished. Also, since the condition that the animation must be on it's own frame 1 to begin pretty much also fixed the problem with holding down the key and repeatedly starting the animation (although, you can just continuously hold down the key and it will start the attack over once the animation is complete, but I don't think that's a big problem...if it is let me know).

Try all of this, tell me how many bugs there are because I did this from memory, up vote if it helps, =).

Comment: Thanks for the help but i can't seem to make it work, i'll just do more tutorials or just give up on it, i guess coding/programming is not for everyone thanks anyway

Comment: Search "Micheal James Avoider Game Tutorial" in google. I think that's one of the best ones out there that teaches you how to make a complete game. It probably will take you about a week to get through if you redo it yourself and learn it well by making your own game that is similar, but I promise after a week or so you'll be much more comfortable